# CLI Argument Value Management

Tags: python

## Background

I've recently made a contribution to an open source project, `ledger-autosync`, which is a CLI "to pull down transactions from your bank and create ledger transactions for them".

Most of the functions are fairly stand alone which means passing configuration values from the argument parser to the function where it is actually used can be very tedious. For example, in [the contribution I made](https://github.com/egh/ledger-autosync/pull/95), of 62 lines added, about 55 or so were updating function calls and signatures to pass the new parameter along.

I submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/egh/ledger-autosync/pull/100) to use a module to manage the configuration global which I think will simplify things and am seeking a review on the approach used.

## My Solution

The approach is to use a `config` module as a namespace for command line argument values.  Then functions that use argument values can access them as attributes of `config` instead of declaring them in their signature and needing them to be passed along.

## My Concerns

I'm worried this global approach will cause issues in ways I can't foresee. One issue I already ran into was the need to update the test suite in order to clear all attributes of `config` between tests.

I'm also worried this approach will make it unclear what command line arguments control a given function, which could make writing tests and understanding the code difficult.

## The Code

Below is a working representation of the code.  The project this is a part of is quite large and I'm not sure of another coherent way to present everything here.

`config.py`

```py
# no content
```

`cli.py`

```py
import argparse
import datetime as dt
import config


def run():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--date-format")

    args = parser.parse_args(namespace=config)

    print_transactions()


def print_transactions():
    transactions = [(dt.date(2020, 5, 1), 10), (dt.date(2020, 5, 2), 100)]
    for t in transactions:
        print(format_transaction(t))


def format_transaction(transaction):
    return f"{transaction[0]:{config.date_format}}:\t {transaction[1]}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Example usage:

```
python cli.py --date-format '%Y/%m/%d'
```

Example output:

```
2020/05/01:  10
2020/05/02:  100
```